# How to use "that"

Tags: relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, subordinators

The following passage comes from a CNN article:

> Ryan's comments come as one senior House GOP member told CNN enough House Republicans are likely to agree to a push for legislation that would ban bump stocks **that something could pass in the GOP-controlled House.**

I can't connect the second "that clause" to the appropriate antecedent. Could anyone explain the use of "that" in this sentence?

Comment: Could it be that it should read "so that something could pass..."? That is, "so" has been accidentally omitted.

Answer (score 2):

If we remove the parts of the text that are extraneous to your question we have:

> Enough House Republicans are likely to agree to a push for legislation
>   that something could pass in the GOP-controlled House.

So this boils down to an *enough ... that* construction.

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p396) notes that *enough* "*licenses purpose expressions*" in the form of an infinitival clause. Reconstructing the original text with an infinitival clause would result in something like:

> Enough House Republicans are likely to agree to a push for legislation
>   to enable something to pass in the GOP-controlled House

which is not particularly felicitous.

However, the CGEL also notes:

> AmE allows an alternative construction in which *enough* takes a
>   resultative content clause:
>
> - %There was enough hot water that we could all take baths.

The percentage sign in front of a sentence is the CGEL's way of indicating that the construction is "*grammatical in some dialects only*". As a British English native speaker I do not find the construction unacceptable. The issue in the current example seems to be that *enough* is quite remote from its resultative content clause.

Answer (score 0):

This was not an easy sentence to parse. In my opinion, the author should've simplified this using punctuation or breaking it into smaller chunks.

But I do think I know what it's referring to:

> **one senior House GOP member told CNN enough House Republicans are likely to agree to a push** [for legislation that would ban bump stocks] **that something could pass in the GOP-controlled House**

In other words, the amount of (likely agreeing) House Republicans is high enough that it could lead to something actually passing in the GOP-controlled house.